# php artisan migrate. Multiple primary key defined

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, migration, mysql-error-1068

**My problem**

I'm building my first api using Laravel  and am getting a multiple primary key defined error while trying to run `php artisan migrate` I don't understand how I have defined multiple primary keys. Every time I run a migrate I get these errors [image: php artisan migrate error].

**My Troubleshooting**

I thought since `autoIncrementing()` can only be used for a primary key that maybe that defined it as a primary key, so I altered `$table->increments('bus_id')->autoIncrement()->primary();` to `$table->increments('bus_id')->autoIncrement();` and `$table->increments('bus_id')->autoIncrement();`

Every time I had tried to run my migrations, I dropped my database and re-created it and tried to run my migrations again (so it was a new database every time with no corrupt data) but still didn't make a difference.

I checked my Connection.php that was mentioned in the picture of my error code above but didn't see anything pertaining to any primary keys.

**My Question**

My code is below, can someone help me understand how I'm making double primary keys?

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePurchaseHistoryTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('purchase_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('pur_id', 11);
            $table->string('pur_item', 255);
            $table->dateTimeTz('pur_date');
            $table->string('bus_name', 50);
            $table->double('pur_amount', 10, 2);
            $table->double('cashback_amount', 10, 2);
            $table->integer('bus_id', 11);
            $table->foreign('bus_id')->references('bus_id')->on('business');   
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken();  
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('purchase_history');
    }
}
```

Please note there are similar questions here on stack overflow which I have also tried their solutions without any success
After edit I'm still getting this error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto colu
> mn and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `purchase_history` (`pur_id` int unsigned not null auto_incre
> ment primary key, `pur_item` varchar(255) not null, `pur_date` datetime not null, `bus_name` varchar(50) not null,
> `pur_amount` double(10, 2) not null, `cashback_amount` double(10, 2) not null, `bus_id` int not null auto_increment
> primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null) default
> character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB)

**After running php artisan migrate:refresh**
[image: migrate:refresh error]

[image: business table]

Comment: `$table->increments(...)` creates an auto-incrementing primary key field.  So `->autoIncrement()->primary()` are both redundant, and probably causing the error.

Comment: Just use `$table->increments('bus_id');`

Comment: ok thanks Ill give that a try. I cant remember off the top of my head If I did.

Comment: @James doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

1. Remove value on `increments`
2. If `bus_id` is and foreign key then `unsigned` it before add `references`
3. **Important:** Make sure `category` has defined/created before `purchase_history` table and category table `auto-increment` field is `bus_id`

---

```
$table->increments('pur_id'); 
$table->integer('bus_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('bus_id')->references('bus_id')->on('category'); 
                                       ^ make sure category table auto increment field value is bus_id
```

---

FYI: If I draw table the I set `id` as a name on the auto-increment field. because no confusion.

Comment: I altered the code to 


'$table->integer('bus_id', 11)->unsigned();
$table->foreign('bus_id', 11)->references('bus_id')->on('business'); '

Category column on  table is


'$table->increments('bus_id', 11);'

Comment: Ill try creating category table first. sorry I miss understood what you meant there. one moment

Comment: I will still trying to work out a kink. Ill update shortly in the comments

Comment: ok so I tried to run the migration with the primary key in my (business) table first by running `php artisan migrate --path=database\migrations\2018_01_30_061115_create_business_table.php` but i get nothing to migrate returned. Sorry its taking me so long to reply. im just trying to figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: does your table having data??

Comment: just columns no data in the columns.

Comment: run `php artisan migrate:fresh` then

Comment: can we move this to chat? I will send you the error i get when I do a refresh

Comment: nvm I cant chat yet. not on SO. ill update my answer with an image.

Comment: Buddy. comment all the code on purchase history table and run `migrate:fresh`. if no errors un-comment one by one and run. and post if there is an error

Comment: Ok so I deleted the db, recreated it now I get `migrate table successful, nothing to migrate`  but if I try and do the exact `php artisan migrate --path= /database/path/other/table` it just says `nothing to migrate

Comment: the problem is here
`$table->integer('bus_id', 11)->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('bus_id', 11)->references('bus_id')->on('business');`

Comment: remove `11` on there and show me the image of `'business'` table

Comment: You were correct, the error was i the 11, not on the business table but on the purchase histiry table for the unisgn and the foreign key

Comment: it was added in answer `$table->integer('bus_id')->unsigned();` :)

Comment: I miss understood that I apologize. thank you so very much. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `autoincrements` and `primary` from your pk definition.

```
$table->increments('bus_id');
```

Definition from the docs:

> Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns

Edit:

The `increments` method only takes one parameter:

```
$table->increments('pur_id');
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_increments

**Edit**

The problem is `bus_id`, its somehow being set as a primary key also. From the exception:

```
`bus_id` int not null auto_increment primary key,
```

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same error. Im gonna update my question to show. I deleted my database and recreated it before doing the migrate. Is there anything else I may have to alter?

Comment: Updated my answer